# How to do binding to items in ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I wrote some controler that have itemsControl. 
Each item in the control is some UserControl that i wrote.

I want to make a binding between the Item source and some collection that i hold:

The Itemscontrol:

```
    <ItemsControl  x:Name="itemsControl" Background="White" >
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The collection that i want to bind with is some List that hold object that will be use to create some 'usercontrol' that will be added to the itemsControl.

How can i do it ? ( i try to do binding to ItemSource - but i dont know how to do it right )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have look at think link

[One stack panel for each record inside table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150456/one-stack-panel-for-each-record-inside-table/6151374#6151374)