# How to do binding of an ItemsControl dynamically

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am binding a `List<>` to an `ItemsControl` as shown below:

`<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Grid.Row="1">`

I need to change this binding dynamically to another `List` on an event.

How to do this? I tried the following, but doesn't work.

`myItemsControl.ItemSource = MyListOther;`

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150456/one-stack-panel-for-each-record-inside-table/6151374#6151374

Answer (score 2):

You can change the reference of `MyList` to another instance of `List<T>`, or you could just repopulate the list that `MyList` references.

Note that assuming you are using the MVVM design pattern, and that `MyList` is a property on your view model (which is the current DataContext), then you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model, and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event when your `MyList` reference changes.

Comment: ok. I don't know MVVM. What resource do you recommend to understand MVVM pattern?

Comment: http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx is a good introduction. Also, you want to use an MVVM framework, I would recommend Caliburn.Micro - http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it's pretty simple, just take a look at code below and everything should be clear.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="list" />
```

Code-behind:

```
private List<string> collection = new List<string> { "test", "2", "3" };
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Source = collection;
    list.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
}
```

Of course need for such resolution may indicate that your architecture is incorrect. You should use `MVVM (Model View ViewModel)` design pattern and than implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to notify your `View` that list was changed. This way there would be no need to manually create bindings in code behind. Also, you could use `ObservableCollection<T>` which would automatically notify `Views` that use this list each time new element was added or removed.

Those are just hints for you to consider while you're implementing your applications. If you're writting just some simple test code, code behind isn't that bad, but in bigger applications try `MVVM` approach.